# Exercise with a series of complex functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given the function $$f (z)=\sum_1^\infty 
\frac 1 {e^{nz}-1}$$ I have to 1) show that $f $ is holomorphic in $\Pi=\{z\in \mathbb C:\mathrm {Re} (z)\gt 0\}$; 2) calculate $$\int_{C_{\frac 1 2} (1)} \frac {f (z)}{(z-1)^2}dz$$ and $$\lim _{j\to \infty}\int_{C_{\frac 1 2} (j)} \frac {f (z)}{(z-j)^2}dz.$$
For the first point, the series converges pointwise to a continuous function for every  $z\in \Pi $, so it converges uniformly in every compact subset of $\pi$; since the terms of the series are holomorphic functions, $f $ is holomorphic. However I don't know if I have done well I the other point: I just found the derivative of $g_n = \frac 1 {e^{nz}-1}$ and I wrote $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n '(1)$ and $\lim_{j\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n '(j)$. However these two sums don't seem to converge to a particular value (we can just say that they converge), so I think that probably there is another way to solve this problem. Thank you in advance

Comment: I forgot to say that $C_r (z)$ is the circle with centre in $z $ and radius $r$

Comment: "the series converges pointwise to a continuous function for every  $z\in \Pi $, so it converges uniformly in every compact subset of $\Pi$;" Why do you say this?

Comment: The sum of continuous functions is a continuous function, so the limit of the series must be continuous. Since the $g_n$ are non negative, the succession of the partial sums is a succession of non decreasing functions converging to a continuous function,  so the convergence must be uniform over the compact sets (Dini's theorem)

Comment: No, the limit of continuous functions need not be continuous. Also, the $g_n$ are complex valued, not nonnegative.

Comment: So how should I proceed to demonstrate that $f $ is holomorphic? Thank you